# Flutter run never loads on vs code and sometimes crashes on android studio on my chromebook

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, chromebook

I recently installed Flutter on my Chromebook (4 GB RAM[image]). I have been writing snippets of dart code using vscode with no issues. Recently, I decided to move into the flutter framework, and then when I try to run the default application generated after creating a new project, VS Code freezes after a while. I know initially this was supposed to take a while to load being my first time, but is over 1 hour the appropriate time?

I have tried restarting VS Code several times, but still the same output. I even switched to using Android Studio, and this even crashes after a while.

What could be wrong or what am I getting wrong? I followed the official installation process on both VS Code and Flutter.dev sites.

[image: Image showing the terminal after running the "flutter run" command]

Comment: Same here after moving from Windows to Linux Debian 11. "Flutter run" works only from terminal and only with very small apps. Otherwise complete computer freezes, no mouse, no keyboard anymore.

Comment: 4GB Ram is not enough. 8GB is minimum. On Windows you may be able to compile or debug small projects with 4GB on VSCode but on Linux you compile barely anything due to a different memory management. That said, since I have a new laptop special for coders with 16GB RAM, all problems vanished.

Comment: Getting a new laptop will be the only solution then. Thanks for your help 

Answer (score 1):

i will assume that you have set up your emulator correctly and you opened the emulator with these steps:

1- on your keyboard use `ctrl + shift + p` and choose `Flutter: Select Device` and wait for the emulator to open.

2- after the emulator starts, from the upper menu of VSCode select Run > Run without debugging.

the app should run, if the problem persists, in VSCode open a new terminal window and type :

1- `flutter upgrade`

2- `flutter clean`

3- `flutter pub get`

try to run the application hopefully it will run

Comment: the emulator won't even load. Right frim the point of selecting the emulator, the whole IDE freezes. I am guessing my chromebook can't carry the workload of creating flutter applications.

Comment: what is the device specs? if ram is below 8 and no SSD I think yes it will not load, you can basically select the browser and adjust the browser to phone view for a start.

Comment: Then getting a new laptop is the only solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When it works only in terminal, you may have forgotten to select a device in vscode debug tasks menu that can cause complete system freeze.

Comment: I didn't forget. Right from the point I select the device to use as an emulator, the pc freezes completely. I think the chromebook hardware isn't sufficient enough to implement flutter and run emulator, except there is something else I am missing of which at this point I don't think so